# mySQL syntax error in INSERT Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I get the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES ('test123', 'Robert','304ce2418de993defe9b5026de389b82267465b4')' at line 1
```

this is my query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO apps (name, developer, key) VALUES ('$name', '$user', '$key') ")
```

does anyone see the problem?